# Can i use salesforce approval process from wf and approval for the record create through opportunity (controller extension)

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger

I creat opportunity record using custom controller and create list page so and now i need to create approval process for that record can i create this manually means through salesforce approval process or i need to create through trigger i have created through approval but after click on submit for approval i am getting error"Unable to Submit for Approval
This record does not meet the entry criteria or initial submiters of any active approval processes. Please contact your administrator for assistance"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create an approval process via trigger. They can only be created in the UI.

To summarize, your issue is one of the following:

- You have no approval process
- Your approval process has incorrect entry criteria
- Your controller is creating the opportunity with incorrect values for the fields required by the approval process.
- The person submitting for approval is not allowed to do so

Please review [this trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/business_process_automation/units/approvals) for information on setting up approval processes.

**For more help:**

Please provide as much detail about your approval process as possible (maybe screenshots of the approval process) as well as about the record you are trying to submit (the code from your controller). When you update your question, Ill update my answer to try to provide more specific help.

Comment: ya it work i deleted previous one and create another one but i want to ask one question that  when opportunity is greater than 50K go to user 1 and if opp is greater than 1 lac go to another user so Can i apply both condition in one approval process or need to create diferent approval process

Comment: If it worked, click the check mark next to my answer to show anyone else who stumbles upon your question what the solution was. If you have another question please post it as a new question to give other's the chance to answer it.